# Creating a click and drag system in GameMaker Studio 2

Tags: game-design, game-maker

I am attempting to create a click and drag system in GameMaker 2, for example a dress-up game or maybe a puzzle. How would I go about getting the objects to click and drag?

I'm trying to get it so I can click and drag a piece of clothing, for example, and drag it onto a character and then drag another piece of clothing on as well.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Try to be specific about your issue, so we can focus on one thing and help you work it out.

Comment: I've tried having an object snap to my mouse x and y cords when left mouse button is pressed but the problem is everything I set that to snaps to my mouse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all your objects move at the mouse position at the same time, probably their *Step* event looks like this:

```
// Click and drag object
if (mouse_check_button(mb_left) && position_meeting(mouse_x, mouse_y, self))
{
    x = mouse_x;
    y = mouse_y;
}
```

Or at least, this is the GML equivalent of what is happening.

The code above doesn't take into account whether an instance is actually being clicked on by the user, it cares only about the button click itself.

**Step 1: Individual instance flag**

We give every instance a variable, with a starting value of `false`:

```
grabbed = false;
```

We set its value to `true` when the mouse button is pressed *and* conditions are met; and set it to false when the mouse is released. We can do this by splitting the code between *Left Pressed* event:

```
// Now instance can move
grabbed = true;
```

And *Global Left Released* event:

```
// Now instance must stop
grabbed = false;
```

Finally our *Step* event will loop like this:

```
// Move instance if selected
if (grabbed)
{
    x = mouse_x;
    y = mouse_y;
}
```

Now objects are dragged only if mouse click happened inside their collision mask.

**Step 2: Global instance flag**

The code works fine so far, except if multiple instances are overlapping when you click, they will all snap to the mouse position! To prevent this, we must make sure one instance only is 'grabbed' when clicking before dragging it. To do so, we can use a global variable instead of an individual flag to tell what instance is picked by the cursor, and move it accordingly:

```
global.grabbed = noone;
```

This variable will hold the `id` of the instance that must move around. So, instead of a `true`/`false` approach, we have a `noone`/`id` variable that specifies which particular instance is being moved around. So:

*Left Pressed* event:

```
// Check if instance can be dragged
if (global.grabbed == noone)
    global.grabbed = self;
```

*Global Left Released* event:

```
// Stop dragging
global.grabbed = noone;
```

*Step* event:

```
// Move object if currently grabbed
if (global.grabbed == self)
{
    x = mouse_x;
    y = mouse_y;
}
```

You can also use the `global.grabbed` variable to get info about what the player has picked.